# How to create daily offsite backups of a server, prepared on the server then pushed/pulled offsite?

Tags: server, backup, client

after some weeks of trials, configurations, setups and reading of tuts and howto's i finally got my server working with some services, (email server, music streaming) etc.
During my attempts I also tried different backup solutions, rsnapshot, bacula, luckybackup.
Some solutions I could not get working completely (bacula) others didn't do what I really wanted: Creating a backup of the server, which could be used to restore it, after using a resque, a minimal ubuntu 14 install. 
Since I started from the minimal install to build the server, I'd like to backup the whole thing, without the music / movies (who are on a seperated partition). 
The to be backupclient is a Intel Xeon 16Gig Ram 2 x 3TB HD's in Raid, located in a datacentre.
The to be backupserver is a Intel Quadcore 4GB of Ram 1TB HD located at my home. with Ubuntu 14 Desktop on it.
A second backupserver could be an I7 system, 16GB of Ram, 256 SSD, 3TB HD with Windows 8.1 on it. 
I would like to have some suggestions on how to make such a kind of backup to work.
I don't mind installing / configure things by hand, following a how to or tutorial :) But finding a good one is the trick these days... lots of them are outdated and/or copied ones. (you see the same typos in every tut). Hoping for some advice, greetings, M

Comment: Question is unclear: are you asking how to best backup your system, or how to then copy the backup to another machine?  Or just how to automate the process?

Comment: Actually... both :) Create a backup, move the backup to another computer. When needed restore from that computer back to the original server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a 2 part solution,
1- install FSArchiver

```
sudo apt-get install fsarchiver
```

the way to use it can be found at [www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart](http://www.fsarchiver.org/QuickStart)

The next step is to install an ftp server on the remote machine where you want to save your backup image.

you can then use cron jobs to create the image and to upload it to the ftp server.

Comment: Or you can just use ssh instead of messing with ftp, which is an insecure protocol.

Comment: he can use scp to do the copy from a linux to a linux, but for the windows machine he is better going with ftp